# How to create an SQL view / SQL script that would turn duplicate values to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is it possible to create a view or SQL statement that would produce the output in Image #2 using the data / table in Image #1?

The existing data:
[image]

The desired output
[image]

Comment: Always 3 different "questiontexts"`?

Comment: Search for **Pivoting table** here. There are hundreds of answered questions on it.

Comment: @jarlh Not always. That would change according to the invitationId.

Comment: Then Google:  "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: I have searched for pivot / dynamic pivot prior to opening this question but all pivoting examples made use of an aggregate function such as MAX, SUM, etc. I thought in order to make use of pivoting I needed to use an aggregate function. So I suppose it can be used for my case as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about PIVOTing

```
 SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CustomerID
        FROM Table
    ) as s
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(CustomerID)
        FOR QuestionText IN ('TextAnswer1', 'TextAnswer2', etc..)
    )AS pvt
```